# accounts = ethers.getSigners() undefined

Tags: ethers.js, hardhat

```
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");

describe("deploy", () => {
  let accounts;
  beforeEach(async () => {
    accounts = await ethers.getSigners();
  })
  console.log(accounts[0].address)
})
```

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

my accounts is showing undefined. Anyone else run into this problem.

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers": "^2.0.0",
    "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-ethers": "^3.0.0",
    "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-network-helpers": "^1.0.0",
    "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox": "^3.0.0",
    "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-verify": "^1.0.0",
    "@typechain/ethers-v6": "^0.4.0",
    "@typechain/hardhat": "^8.0.0",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "ethers": "^6.4.0",
    "hardhat": "^2.14.0",
    "hardhat-gas-reporter": "^1.0.8",
    "solidity-coverage": "^0.8.0",
    "typechain": "^8.1.0"
  },
```

the problem was accounts = await ethers.getSigners() was in the beforeEach.

Once you move the accounts = await ethers.getSigners() into it("test somthing") then it works

```
describe("deploy", () => {
    let accounts;
    it("test accounts", async () => {
        accounts = await ethers.getSigners();
        console.log(accounts[0].address);
    }

})
```

Comment: Most likley you are not connected to any network

Comment: thanks for your thoughts, I'm pretty sure I am using hardhat network. How can I check?

Comment: Check your ‘hardhat.config.js’ to see which network

Comment: I did not use the --network flag in the terminal command
`yarn hardhat test`
so by default it should go to hardhat
I have also tried
`yarn hardhat test --network hardhat `
but still does not work...

Comment: I even tried to explicitly state the `defaultNetwork: "hardhat"` in the hardhat.config